# How do I call $_SESSION[‘username’] from one php file to another?

Tags: php, mysql, session

In one of my php files, *DataBase.php*, I have a function called *logIn* where I set $_SESSION[‘username’].

I have another php file, *api.php*, where I would like to use the same $_SESSION[‘username’].

How do I call $_SESSION[‘username’] from the *logIn* function in *DataBase.php* to use it in *api.php*?

Comment: you need to start session on another page in order to access session variables you can start session using : session_start();

Comment: on every file where you want to use `S_SESSION` put `session_start();` on top of that file

Comment: Hi - thanks for you comments. So in every file that I have `session_start();`, I can call these variables? 

For example, in the *DataBase.php* file, I have `session_start()` and `$_SESSION[‘username’] = “Bob”`. Does this mean in the *api.php* file, if I have `session_start()`, and I call `$_SESSION[‘username’]`, it will refer to `Bob`?

Answer (score 0):

This is just typical Cookie usage.

In DataBase.php,

```
session_start();
$_SESSION[‘username’] = 'Hasselhoff';
```

Then to use the 'username' cookie, in any other php file
just run session_start() again and that will be available there.

In OtherFile.php,

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION[‘username’];
```

---

Edit: Using this in a sql query:

```
$userSelected =  $_SESSION[‘username’];
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT product_id, price FROM products WHERE username = '$userSelected'");
$results= $sql ->fetch_assoc();
```

This is basic attempt which is open to vulnerability.
Do read on prevention of sql injection here to make your code safer and
protected from php sql injection:

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Quick question: how would I use this variable with an SQL query? I currently have `SELECT product_id, price FROM products`. I’d like to use `$_SESSION[‘username’]` so that I can have this: `SELECT product_id, price FROM products WHERE username = $username` Where `$username` is `$_SESSION[‘username’]`

Comment: Thanks. I’ve just tried this but it doesn’t seem to work. `SELECT product_id, price FROM products` successfully gives me a list of all the items but when I try `"SELECT product_id, price FROM products WHERE username = '$username'"` it does not return anything. I have also tested it with `"SELECT product_id, price FROM products WHERE username = 'Bob'"` just to see if it filters out any products which has username ‘Bob’ and it does.

Comment: If you copied my code you should use `WHERE username = '$userSelected'`

Comment: I currently have this:

    `session_start();

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    $sql = "SELECT transaction_id, price FROM transactions WHERE username = '$username'";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute();`

Comment: I don't think I am setting `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` correctly. In my *DataBase.php* file, I have a function for *logIn*: `function logIn($table, $username, $password)`. In this, I set `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`. At the top of the file, outside the function, I have `session_start()`.

Comment: if you have a function, then you need to check whether the function has been called or not before moving to api.php. This involves an understanding of the program FLOW. You should check $sql string content, using `echo $sql;` in the DataBase.php. If it says `...WHERE username = ''` then it means the cookie username was never set, probably the login function was never called or other reasons.